# Reactjs & Express 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have created a React/Express server but when trying to import bootstrap I am getting the below:

**Error**

```
./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Button.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   active,
|   className,
|   ...props
| }, ref) => {
|   const prefix = useBootstrapPrefix(bsPrefix, 'btn');
```

**Setup**

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Customers from './components/customers';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">React Express Starter</h1>
        </header>
        <Customers />
        <div>
          <div id="wallet-address"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I have webpack installed on both packages I am just completely lost as to why the issue is occurring. I have done the same without express with no issues but with both Express and React I can't seem to import any package without getting this same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is your button.js look? Is jsx in there?

Comment: @DanielA.White it's the Button component from react-bootstrap

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between Express and your React app? Typically, you'd use the webpack dev server to serve the frontend during development ([proxying](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) API requests through to Express) and have Express [statically serve](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#other-solutions) the `build` directory contents for production

Comment: @DanielA.White It's a package i installed from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Comment: @Phil I'm just starting to learn really and found a youtube video with the git https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_express_starter so it's just that as a base with bootstrap installed.

Answer (score 0):

A typical React / Express dev setup looks like this, assuming your React app dev server runs on port 3000 and Express on 5000...

1. [Proxy API requests](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) to Express. In `client/package.json` add

   ```json
   "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
   ```
2. Start your Express app however you prefer to start it
3. Start your React app via `npm start` / `yarn start` in the app's folder (`client` in your case).
4. Open your browser to `http://localhost:3000`

Make sure when installing client-side libraries like react-bootstrap that you install them in the `client/package.json` file.

---

A [production build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#other-solutions) looks more like this

1. Have Express statically serve files from your `build` directory and handle frontend routes

   ```js
   // make sure this comes after any routes, preferably last
   const path = requires("path");
   const clientBuild = path.join(__dirname, "client", "build");

   app.use(express.static(clientBuild));

   app.get("/*", (_req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.join(clientBuild, "index.html"));
   });
   ```
2. Build your React app via `npm run build` / `yarn build` in the `client` folder.
3. Start your Express app however you prefer to start it
4. Open `http://localhost:5000` in your browser.

Note that making changes to your React app in production mode requires a re-build (step #2).