# How to run React with express.js in dev mode without compiling

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, graphql, apollo-client

Currently, the web app is running node server and react app together. The process is that there will be `npm run build` before starting `npm run dev` which works fine for testing server side codes.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "dev": "nodemon server",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Express file

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-express");

const typeDefs = require('./graphql/schema');
const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers/index');

const app = express();
const customHost = process.env.HOST;
const host = customHost || 'localhost';
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || '3000', 10);

// middlewares
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build", "index.html"));
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

server.start().then(res => {
  server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    path: '/graphql'
  });
  app.listen(({ host, port }), () => {
    console.log(`Now browse to http://${host}:${port} + ${server.graphqlPath}`)
  })
});
```

At the same time, it is not possible to maintain the React components because currently the frontend part running from build folder.

Is there any option to run React app on dev mode without running build process therefore I can work on the component maintenance.

Folder structure

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs & Express 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759585/283366)

Comment: @Phil not really. I am running both backend and frontend on the same port `3000`. The problem is that always need to compile react for testing each changes. here `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")`

Comment: If you want to run React in dev mode with HMR, etc, you'll need to run it on its own port

Comment: Yeah, you would start both the react app and the node server separately and then use a proxy in your package.json for the requests.  It's not practical to run both at the same port for development because every change you make would take ages to recreate the build and start the server. Develop them separately, and add the build folder once you are done.

Comment: @Phil any option to use dev mode by changing this folder `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")`  reference ?

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou ja, I don't want to compile frontend on each and every changes.

Comment: Yeah, change your folder structure and run them separately. Have a front folder and server folder. Inside front is your react app and in server your apollo-express server. Then you can run both in separate ports, make use of webpack for HMR and once done, build and add the build folder in your server

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou It was separate port but some failure when deploy on vercel.com

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou okay

Answer (score 0):

Move React to its own folder, within the react folder run `npm start` then in another terminal tab move to your backend folder and run `npm run dev`. First make sure your React application has a `proxy:`  to your server root url. You will need to change your `res.sendFile` as your build location will have changed.

```
// needs to get updated with your new React folder.
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: Isn't that what OP already has for `sendFile`?