# The edit I made on my react component does not reflect after being served with express

Tags: reactjs, express

I served my react app with an express server every thing worked fine on my local host , but all other edit I made on the react components does not reflect it keeps showing the old data , i thought it was a cache issue i cleared my cache but nothing worked, i deleted everything and started again it still happened

this is my code in my express server

```js
var express = require("express")
const app = express(); 
const path = require('path')


const  reactBuild = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')
app.use(express.static(reactBuild))

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.send("the api")
})

app.get("*", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(reactBuild, 'index.html'))
    
});


app.listen(5001, () => {
    console.log("listening on port 5001")
});
```

i cross checked the pathing everything it's well pathed the build folder is inside the react folder

this is the file path

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYdtX.png)

The edit I Made:

[the components i edited and added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHxYa.png)

it keeps sending old data

[old data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqT2o.png)

Comment: Given Express is serving your React app statically, you would need to rebuild it every time you make changes. I suggest using the React dev server during development instead

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759585/283366) for instructions on running a React / Express app in development and production modes

Comment: Could there be any way i can serve it using the express server without having to re build it after every change ?

Comment: No. _"Static"_ means just that, static, unchanging, fixed, etc. Is there a problem using the React dev server for your frontend during development?

Comment: i just wanted to get familiar with serving it with express , because i use express as my backend server in all my web application . thank you for your help.  i have been stuck with this issue for days .