# Docker copy react and express package json into same WORKDIR

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and I have a express server folder with package.json and a client folder with package.json. I have seen many tutorials out there where they have 2 separate images/containers one client and one server. They both have the same WORKDIR

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]
```

Does this not override one package.json with the other seen as they are in the same WORKDIR ?

My head is spinning reading different tutorials.
Can someone set me straight here.

This was one of the tutorials I was following which has the same WORKDIR for both client and server https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-react-nodejs-application-with-docker-part-i-of-ii-910bc6edb46e

Comment: What makes you think directories in two separate images would conflict? Think of containers as an entirely separate systems.

Comment: So in this case it doesn't really matter what the name is. It could be WORKDIR /app and WORKDIR /server ?

Comment: Is `/tmp` on my computer the same as `/tmp` on yours?

Comment: Ok I get the point. If my server is looking for the client build files in client folder to serve the html then how would server get access to that if they are 2 different systems ?

Comment: The article you linked makes the mistake of using the Webpack dev server in production. That simply will not work. Building your React app into Express' static files is much better though I would probably serve the React app using NGINX with a reverse proxy through to the Express app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of images as templates for a system and containers as instances of those templates.

If you and I both bought brand new computers from the same manufacturer, same OS, etc, would `/app` on mine be the same `/app` on yours? The answer is of course *no*.

The `WORKDIR` is just a directory. It can be helpful if the system you're creating requires known paths but you can name it literally anything you want, with the exception that you wouldn't want to copy your app files into a system directory like `/etc`, `/usr`, etc.

---

To address the Express / React app you're building, I would recommend the following multi-stage `Dockerfile` to produce a single, production-ised image

```sh
## Build stage
FROM node:16-alpine AS build
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /client

COPY client/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY client ./

RUN npm run build

## App stage
FROM node:16-alpine AS app
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY server/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY server ./

# Copy the built React app into your static files dir, eg "public"
COPY --from=build /client/build ./public

RUN npm start
```

---

For local development, if you want to use Docker I'd recommend this compose setup

```sh
# dev.Dockerfile
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
CMD npm start
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: ../dev.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./client:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules" # don't overwrite node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # adjust accordingly
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ../dev.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./server:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000" # adjust accordingly
```

Make sure you proxy requests from your React app to the server. In `client/package.json`, add

```json
"proxy": "http://server:5000"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759585/283366) to help understand the differences between *development* and *production* modes for such an application.

To run it, you simply execute

```sh
docker compose up
```

Then open `http://localhost:3000` in your browser. Thanks to the `proxy` config in `dev` and having Express serve the files statically in prod, the React app can make requests to your Express API using path-only URLs, eg

```js
axios.post("/api/login", { username, password });
```

Comment: Makes sense. So if I have 2 containers one called client and the other called server. How would server be able to server up static files that would be in client. Would I someone have to copy the build files from client into server container. Or could I have another container called static files that server can serve the files from ?

Comment: Ah I see ok this makes sense. Would I have to create another dockerfile file for development.

Comment: Now I'm wanting each developer to have the same setup so by using docker I was hoping to accomplish that. But I want to be able to run docker in production and development. I started out with something like you have then I moved to using compose with 2 containers and now I'm back to what you have agin.

Comment: So a Dockerfile in the root for the prod build. Then for dev a dev.Dockerfile in both client and server folders and docker-compose.yml in root.

Comment: Not quite, I didn't see a reason to use a different `Dockerfile` for each service since they both do the same thing so `dev.Dockerfile` is just a single file in the root

Comment: This is starting to make more sense now. As far as the "proxy": "http://server:5000" will this allow Express to serve static files in development. I thought I would still have to do a build every time.  Currently my express is looking for a build folder const rootBuildPath = path.join(__dirname, "client/build");
const indexPath = `${rootBuildPath}/index.html`;

Comment: @me-me no, you won't want to use static files during development, otherwise you'll have to rebuild your React app to see any change. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759585/283366) for more details

Comment: That works if you are just building front end in development but what if you want to test login features. Then express has no idea about what files to serve.

Comment: @me-me it doesn't need to know them. The Webpack dev server serves your React app and the `proxy` config lets you make requests to your Express API as if they were all on the same host

Comment: But it does because my login page is a separate view page in express using Ouath flow which if success then routes to / which is still handled in express app.get("*", isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(indexPath);
});    index path been the files in client folder  const indexPath = `${rootBuildPath}/index.html`;

Comment: Ah, now I understand. In that case, I would configure an environment variable with the base URL for the front-end. In dev it would be `http://localhost:3000/` but in prod it would be `/`

Comment: You might be interested n something like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) which does a much better job of tightly coupling the client and server apps. Running two separate apps like you are, I'd be more inclined to treat React as a SPA and use JWTs when communicating with the server

Comment: I'm not understanding that last part. a base url you mean for the OAuth paths ?

Comment: Sorry, this discussion is getting wildly off-course. Not sure I can help much more as I wouldn't build an app the way you are. You should definitely consider Next.js I think

Comment: Ok you have been very helpful so far so thank you for the help. I'll start another topic after I've implemented all this.